# Different experiments related and their sample spaces

Tags: probability

I'm having a doubt in applications of the law of total probability because in most of examples it **seems** that the law is being used when dealing with different sample spaces. I'll explain what I mean: the law of total probability says that if $E_1,\dots,E_n$ is a partition of the sample space, that is they are pairwise disjoint and their union is the sample space, then for some event $A$ we have:

$$P(A) =\sum_iP(A|E_i)P(E_i)$$

For this $A$ and $E_i$ must all be events on the same sample space. Now, there are some examples of problems where it seems that we are dealing with different sample spaces.

For instance the following experiment: "inside one urn there are three balls numbered $(1,2,3)$. First we pick one ball. If we pick the $i$-th ball we select $i$ light bulbs from a sample of bulbs where $60$% are deffective. What's the probability of no light bulbs be deffective?"

The problem is that for me there are two experiements: "picking a ball" with sample space $\Omega_1=\{1,2,3\}$ and picking light bulbs and with the property that the sample space of the second depends on the first. So, for result $1$ in the first experiment, the second has sample space $\Omega_{2,1} = \{1, 0\}$ where $1$ stands for non deffective and $1$ for deffective. If the result on the first is $2$ then the second has sample space $\Omega_{2,2}= \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$ and in analogous manner for $3$ on the first experiment.

The solution of the problem is that if $A$ is the event where no bulbs are deffective, then we have

$$P(A) = P(A|i = 1)P(i = 1) + P(A|i=2)P(i=2) + P(A|i=3)P(i=3)$$

But in my setting this doesn't make sense, because $A$ is in one sample space and $i = k$ is an event on another sample space.

What am I missing in this kind of problem? I think I'm not getting really how to set the sample space when we have different experiments related. Like "do an experiment, and for each possible value do another different experiment".

How is the right way to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction. In general, suppose you first roll a $k$-sided die to figure out which of $k$ experiments to conduct. When your result is $j$, then conduct the $j$th experiment.

Now imagine that you're conducting all $k$ experiments anyway (as in your case, designate all 3 bulbs), but if the roll came up $j$ then in the calculation of the outcome you simply disregard the result of all other ($i \ne j$) experiments.

For example: $j=2$, the bulbs are $0,1,0$. Since $j=2$, only count the first two bulbs $0,1$. $A$ = {Out of first $j$ bulbs, neither is defective}. The combined outcome is $(2,0,1,0)$ (write $j$ first). This outcome does not belong to $A$.  But the outcome $(1,0,1,0)$ does.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider a sample space for the combined experiment, where an outcome
consists of an outcome for the first experiment and an outcome for the second experiment.